# Где можно посмотреть исходный код .NET Framework?

Tags: .net

Microsoft выложила исходные коды .NET Framework.
Где можно посмотреть исходный код .NET Framework?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Зависит от того, что именно вы хотите посмотреть. Думаю, вам будут полезны следующие ссылки:

- .NET Framework BCL: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/
- .NET Core: https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet
- .NET Core Foundational Libraries (CoreFX): https://github.com/dotnet/corefx
- .NET Compiler Platform (Roslyn): https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn
- .NET Official Homepage на GitHub: https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet
- .NET Micro Framework: https://netmf.codeplex.com/
- .NET Foundation: http://www.dotnetfoundation.org/projects

Answer (score 2):

На Гитхабе вестимо. [Вот ту](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet)т например есть ссылки.
Ну либо можно с помощью какого-нибудь декомпилятора (dotPeek например) поковыряться в сборках

Comment: Вроде там опубликованы коды разрабатываемых библиотек.

Comment: @MaLS там опубликованы актуальные исходники, но еще не все. Они потихоньку выкладывают.

Comment: @MaLS помимо библиотек там еще и .NET Core

Answer (score 2):

Здесь, http://referencesource.microsoft.com/, выложены исходники последнего дистрибутива.

Comment: Кстати, этот сайт доступен и по более запоминаемому адресу: http://sourceof.net